# Landau symbol and taylor series

Tags: real-analysis

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}-\sqrt x=\frac{1}{2}$$

I saw the calculation $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}-\sqrt x=$$...$$=\sqrt x (\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1/x+\sqrt{1/x^3}}}-1)= $$ $$\sqrt x(1+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1/x+\sqrt{1/x^3}}+ \color{red}{\mathcal o \left(1/x+\sqrt{1/x^3}\right)}-1)=...$$

Main question: Now wouldn't it have to be $\mathcal o(\sqrt{1/x+\sqrt{1/x^3}})$ instead?  So I could write $\mathcal o(\sqrt{1/x+\sqrt{1/x^3}})$ or $\mathcal O(1/x+\sqrt{1/x^3})$?

Are there other ways to calculate the limit?

Comment: What is $\left(\sqrt x + \frac{1}{2}\right)^2?$ By how much does it differ from the square of the term on the left?

Comment: I don't get it. Is this a comment to my first question or 2nd?

Comment: other ways, I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that $o(1/x + \sqrt{1/x^3})$ is incorrect there. Given the calculation being done, I would have expected either $O(1/x + \sqrt{1/x^3})$ to appear there, or $o(\sqrt{1/x + \sqrt{1/x^3}})$, as you said. It's probably just a typo.

Answer (score 4):

An overkill is to exploit that for any sufficiently large $x>0$ we have that
$$ \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\ldots}}}} = \frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{4}}$$
since both terms are a positive solution of $y^2=x+y$. On the other hand
$$ \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}} \geq \frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{x-\frac{1}{4}} $$
is a trivial inequality by just squaring both sides, hence
$$ \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}-\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{2} $$
is bounded between $\sqrt{x-\frac{1}{4}}-\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{4}}-\sqrt{x}$, and the limit is $\color{red}{\large\frac{1}{2}}$ by squeezing.

Comment: Jack, he seems mostly concerned with the use of the $o;$  I put that part in red and split the expression into separate lines, I think I got that aspect correct. It seems he is copying that whole thing from a book or solution manual

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it with an asymptotic expansion, you have to be cautious with the order of expansion. The scale of comparison will be the powers of $\sqrt x$, and we'll expand $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\dfrac1x+\sqrt{\dfrac1{x^3}}}}$ at order $2\;$ (i.e. up to a term in $1/x$).

- $\sqrt{\dfrac1x+\sqrt{\dfrac1{x^3}}}=\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\biggl(\sqrt{1+\dfrac1{\sqrt{x}}} \biggr)=\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\biggl(1+\dfrac1{2\sqrt{x}}+o\Bigl(\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\Bigr) \biggr)=\dfrac1{\sqrt x}+\dfrac1{2x}+o\Bigl(\dfrac1x\Bigr)$, so that:
- $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\dfrac1x+\sqrt{\dfrac1{x^3}}}}=\sqrt{1+\dfrac1{\sqrt x}+\dfrac1{2x}+o\Bigl(\dfrac1x\Bigr)}=$

\begin{align*}&=1+\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt x}+\dfrac1{4x}-\dfrac18\Bigl(\dfrac1{\sqrt x}+\dfrac1{2x}\Bigr)^2+o\Bigl(\dfrac1x\Bigr)=1+\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt x}+\dfrac1{4x}-\dfrac1{8x}+o\Bigl(\dfrac1x\Bigr)\\
&=1+\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt x}-\dfrac1{8x}+o\Bigl(\dfrac1x\Bigr)
\end{align*}
Thus,
\begin{align*}\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}-\sqrt{\mathstrut  x}&=\sqrt{\mathstrut x} \biggl(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1/x+\sqrt{1/x^3}}}-1\biggr)=\sqrt{\mathstrut x} \biggl(1+\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt x}-\dfrac1{8x}+o\Bigl(\dfrac1x\Bigr)-1\Biggr)\\&=\frac12-\frac1{8\sqrt x}+o\Bigl(\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\Bigr).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I accepted another one as it answered my initial question!

Answer (score 1):

Use formula $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}=\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}$ in order to get:
$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}-\sqrt x=\frac{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}+\sqrt{x}}.$$ 
Now divide numerator and denumerator with $\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}$ and calculate the limit:
$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1+\frac{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}{x}}{1+\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}}}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1+0}{1+0}}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+0}}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you! But my main question (I edited my question just now to make it clear) was the first question!

Comment: @Lan I should point out that the part you seem to have typeset that includes the Landau symbol goes off  and is blocked by some stuff on the right side of the screen. Maybe i will break that into two lines or so. That is part of why people are not responding in detail about the $o$ stuff.

Comment: @Lan alright, take a look at your question, refresh the screen first. Your way of writing this is a little unusual in any case, but it seems to be unambiguous once we can make out exactly to what quantity the $o$ applies.

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks for the editing! What is unusual? Maybe I can fix it! Your red marking is right on point, it markes the quantity the $\mathcal o$ applies to!

Comment: @Lan good, perhaps someone will answer directly about that aspect. Don't worry too much about the mathematical aspects, just remember to check whether everything is actually visible to someone else reading your question.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}-\sqrt{x}\right)
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}-\sqrt{x}\right)\frac{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}+\sqrt{x}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}+\sqrt{x}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac1x}}}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac1x+\sqrt{\frac1{x^3}}}}+1}\\
&=\frac12
\end{align}
$$